# Rails API: Use Pundit outside controllers - in rake tasks

Tags: rake, rails-api, pundit

I'm using [Pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) in some Rails API controllers and wonder how it will work/escaped outside of it, for example in Rake tasks. I haven't played around with it yet. Can we skip the authorization in a Rake task? In this case, it will be run as ActiveJob with Sidekiq and there will be no User instance in the context.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using belgoro's example policy above, it is possible to create an instance of the policy and check against it.  E.g.:

```
if ShopPolicy.new(current_user, shop).update?
  shop.update!(...)
end
```

The trick here is knowing what user it is running under.  Unless you prompt for it, there probably is know way of knowing *who* is running the rake task.

Answer (score -1):

I've just tried it out. It seemed to work as usual.
Here is my simple `ShopPolicy`:

```rb
class ShopPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def update?
    user.admin?
  end
end
```

I have a created a simple rake task as follows:

```
namespace :batch do
  desc 'Update a shop without Pundit'
  task update_shop_fax: :environment do
    shop = Shop.find_by(identifier: 12345)
    shop.update!(fax: '0800-123456789')
    puts 'Done'
  end
end
```

Then I run it as `rails batch:update_shop_fax`.
And it worked, the fax value was updated.